# Error when trying to deploy node.js on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting errors when trying to deploy `Node.js` app to Google App Engine. `Node.js` run time get crashed with require statement. What am I wrong?

**Directory structure:**

|--app
    ---protocol.js
   app.js .....

**In file app.js**

```
.....
var protocol = require('./app/protocol');
....
```

When deploying with gcloud:

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

then errors:

```
> nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0 start /app
> node app.js

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './app/protocol'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:21:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/nodejs/bin/node" "/nodejs/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nodejs-getting-started@1.0.0 start script 'node app.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the nodejs-getting-started package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node app.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs nodejs-getting-started
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls nodejs-getting-started
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Getting same issue.

Comment: is the issue solved?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325957/why-subfolders-are-not-deployed-to-google-app-engine-nodejs-app

Answer (score 1):

The error was reported to the google SDK issue reporting,

https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=1431

It was solved by downgrading to 137.0.1

gcloud components update --version=137.0.1

and redoing the process.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue trying to deploy a Sails.js project. Downgrading gcloud from 138.0.0 to 137.0.1 also fixed my issue.